# Xamarin IOS development : .itmsp for myApp.ipa can not be created

Tags: ios, xamarin

As be new to Xamarin and iOS development I get stuck on upload my IPA file to the AppStore.

I get the message
".itmsp for myApp.ipa can not be created"
no Apprecords found. Check bundle ID "com.mycompany.project"*  is correct."

The bundle id I've copied is **exactly** the same as in the Apple Developer Certificates App Id Configuration. (there's 1 capital in the ID)

So I'm confused and stuck.

```
info.plist:
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.mycompany.project</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

i find out that in the App store you've to add a page for the app before you can upload